# Transpose of data.frame turns first row into a list

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, transpose

I have data as follows:

```
library(data.table)
DF <- structure(list(toberevised = c("Number of returns", "Number of joint returns", 
"Number with paid preparer's signature"), `SOUTH DAKOTA_All returns` = c(135257620, 
52607676, 80455243), `SOUTH DAKOTA_Under_50000` = c(92150166, 
20743943, 53622647)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

I would like the first column as variables and the variables in a column so I did:

```
DF<- as.data.frame(t(DF))
setnames(DF, DF[1,])
```

But then I get the error:

```
Passed a vector of type 'list'. Needs to be type 'character'
```

I have tried everything I could think of to unlist the list, but to no avail.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Try `unlist(DF[1,])`. So this should do it `setNames(DF, unlist(DF[1,]))`

Comment: The desired output is unclear, but my guess is `transpose(DF, make.names = "toberevised")`, where 'DF' is the original DF.

Comment: @Sotos `setNames(DF, unlist(DF[1,]))` did the trick! Simply unlisting somehow did not. Any idea what makes this happen?

Comment: @Henrik I get an error when I use your solution. `Error in transpose(DF, make.names = "toberevised") : 
  unused argument (make.names = "toberevised")`

Comment: What do you mean *simply unlisting*? You mean the whole data frame?

Comment: Then you have an old version of `data.table`. `make.names` was introduced in [1.2.4](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md#datatable-v1124--03-oct-2019) (current CRAN version is 1.2.8).

Comment: @Sotos I tried `DF <- as.data.frame(t(DF));
DF[1,] <- unlist(DF[1,]);
setnames(DF, DF[1,])`, but that still gives the same error.

Comment: @Henrik My data.table version says 1.12.6, but I will try to update it and see what happens. Thanks

Comment: oh...well you can't really unlist something and save it in a data frame. Remember, data frames are lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transposing a data.frame is dangerous because `t()` returns a matrix where all elements ("cells") have been coerced to the same data type:

```
t(DF)
```

> ```
>                          [,1]                [,2]                      [,3]                                   
> toberevised              "Number of returns" "Number of joint returns" "Number with paid preparer's signature"
> SOUTH DAKOTA_All returns "135257620"         " 52607676"               " 80455243"                            
> SOUTH DAKOTA_Under_50000 "92150166"          "20743943"                "53622647"
> ```

Now, all numeric values have been coerced to type character which was not intended, propably.

As mentioned several times before, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62007661/3817004) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62008338/3817004), I recommend to reshape data into a tidy format, i.e., long format, to simplify data processing:

```
library(data.table)
long <- melt(DF, id.vars = "toberevised")
long
```

> ```
>                              toberevised                 variable     value
> 1:                     Number of returns SOUTH DAKOTA_All returns 135257620
> 2:               Number of joint returns SOUTH DAKOTA_All returns  52607676
> 3: Number with paid preparer's signature SOUTH DAKOTA_All returns  80455243
> 4:                     Number of returns SOUTH DAKOTA_Under_50000  92150166
> 5:               Number of joint returns SOUTH DAKOTA_Under_50000  20743943
> 6: Number with paid preparer's signature SOUTH DAKOTA_Under_50000  53622647
> ```

From long format, we can reshape into the desired wide format:

```
dcast(long, variable ~ toberevised)
```

> ```
>                    variable Number of joint returns Number of returns Number with paid preparer's signature
> 1: SOUTH DAKOTA_All returns                52607676         135257620                              80455243
> 2: SOUTH DAKOTA_Under_50000                20743943          92150166                              53622647
> ```

Now, the numbers are still of type numeric.

---

As a rule of thumb, whenever a column name is to be treated as an attribute, like  `SOUTH DAKOTA_Under_50000` it is likely that the data is not in tidy format. Attributes should be stored and treated as data items in order to use it for subsetting, grouping, and aggregation.

Actually,  `SOUTH DAKOTA_Under_50000` contains two attributes, a region and a classification.