# Using lapply to create new columns based on old columns

Tags: r, data.table, lapply

My data looks as follows:

```
DF <- structure(list(No_Adjusted_Gross_Income = c(183454, 241199, 249506
), NoR_from_1_to_5000 = c(1035373, 4272260, 1124098), NoR_from_5000_to_10000 = c(319540, 
4826042, 1959866)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
val <- c(2500.5, 7500)
vn <- c("AGI_from_1_to_5000", "AGI_from_5000_to_10000")

   No_Adjusted_Gross_Income NoR_from_1_to_5000 NoR_from_5000_to_10000
1:                   183454            1035373                 319540
2:                   241199            4272260                4826042
3:                   249506            1124098                1959866
```

I would like to create new columns, based on column 2 and 3, multiplied with the values from `val`, using the names from `vn`. I tried to do it as follows:

```
DF[,2:3] <- lapply(DF[,2:3], vn := val*DF[,2:3])
```

But this does not work..

Desired output:

```
DF <- setDT(DF)[, vn[1]:=val[1]*DF[,2]]
DF <- setDT(DF)[, vn[2]:=val[2]*DF[,3]]

DFout <- structure(list(No_Adjusted_Gross_Income = c(183454, 241199, 249506
), NoR_from_1_to_5000 = c(1035373, 4272260, 1124098), NoR_from_5000_to_10000 = c(319540, 
4826042, 1959866), AGI_from_1_to_5000 = c(2588950186.5, 10682786130, 
2810807049), AGI_from_5000_to_10000 = c(2396550000, 36195315000, 
14698995000)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))

   No_Adjusted_Gross_Income NoR_from_1_to_5000 NoR_from_5000_to_10000 AGI_from_1_to_5000 AGI_from_5000_to_10000
1:                   183454            1035373                 319540         2588950187             2396550000
2:                   241199            4272260                4826042        10682786130            36195315000
3:                   249506            1124098                1959866         2810807049            14698995000
```

Comment: how do you calculate the `AGI_from_5000_to_10000` colum? for me 319540 * 7500 = 2396550000

Comment: Where was `vn` defined in your code?

Comment: Both are typos, my apologies. It should be correct now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.. `lapply()` is not needed

```
library( data.table )
setDT( DF )
DF[, (var) := as.data.table ( t( t( DF[, 2:3] ) * val ) ) ][]


#    No_Adjusted_Gross_Income NoR_from_1_to_5000 NoR_from_5000_to_10000 AGI_from_1_to_5000 AGI_from_5000_to_10000
# 1:                   183454            1035373                 319540         2588950187             2396550000
# 2:                   241199            4272260                4826042        10682786130            36195315000
# 3:                   249506            1124098                1959866         2810807049            14698995000
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I was wondering, does your solution also allow for a grouping variable? I am trying to apply your solution in a different context. In this case I want as output, the sum of the values in the column by group. I tried to do something like `DF[, (var) := as.data.table ( t( t( DF[, 2:3] , by="No_Adjusted_Gross_Income")  ) ) ][]`, but it then gives the error `unused argument`. If I place `by` further outside, it gives no error but it does not give the right results.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `apply` to get your values, then use `cbind` if you want to combine with your original DF

```
t(apply(DF[,2:3],1, function(x) x*val ))

 NoR_from_1_to_5000 NoR_from_5000_to_10000
[1,]         2588950187             2396550000
[2,]        10682786130            36195315000
[3,]         2810807049            14698995000
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, where would the variable names `vn` go in this case?

Comment: if you assigned the above code as an object named `NewCols` you could use `colnames(NewCols) <- vn` before using the `cbind`

Answer (score 1):

The OP has asked in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62004219/using-lapply-to-create-new-columns-based-on-old-columns#comment109665625_62004826) for a grouping variable.

Although the accepted answer apparently does what the OP initially has asked for I would like to suggest a completey different approach where the data is stored and processed in *tidy (long) format*. IMHO, processing data in long format is much more straightforward and flexible (which includes aggregation & grouping).

For this, the dataset is reshaped from wide, Excel-style format to long, SQL-style format by

```
library(data.table)
col <- "NoR"
long <- melt(DF, measure.vars = patterns(col), value.name = col, variable.name = "range")
long[, range := stringr::str_remove(range, paste0(col, "_"))]
long
```

> ```
>    No_Adjusted_Gross_Income              range     NoR
> 1:                   183454     from_1_to_5000 1035373
> 2:                   241199     from_1_to_5000 4272260
> 3:                   249506     from_1_to_5000 1124098
> 4:                   183454 from_5000_to_10000  319540
> 5:                   241199 from_5000_to_10000 4826042
> 6:                   249506 from_5000_to_10000 1959866
> ```

In tidy (long) format there is one row for each observation and one column for each variable (see [Chapter 12.2 of Hadley Wickham's book *R for Data Science*](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html#tidy-data-1).

The vector of multipliers `val` also needs to be reshaped from wide to long format:

```
valDF <- long[, .(range = unique(range), val)]
valDF
```

> ```
>                 range    val
> 1:     from_1_to_5000 2500.5
> 2: from_5000_to_10000 7500.0
> ```

Now, `valDF` is also in tidy format as there is one row for each `range`.

Finally, we can add a new column `AGI` to `DF` by an *update join*:

```
long[valDF, on = "range", AGI := val * NoR][]
```

> ```
>    No_Adjusted_Gross_Income              range     NoR         AGI
> 1:                   183454     from_1_to_5000 1035373  2588950187
> 2:                   241199     from_1_to_5000 4272260 10682786130
> 3:                   249506     from_1_to_5000 1124098  2810807049
> 4:                   183454 from_5000_to_10000  319540  2396550000
> 5:                   241199 from_5000_to_10000 4826042 36195315000
> 6:                   249506 from_5000_to_10000 1959866 14698995000
> ```

If required for presentation, the dataset can be reshaped back from long to wide format:

```
dcast(long, No_Adjusted_Gross_Income ~ range, value.var = c("NoR", "AGI"))
```

> ```
>    No_Adjusted_Gross_Income NoR_from_1_to_5000 NoR_from_5000_to_10000 AGI_from_1_to_5000 AGI_from_5000_to_10000
> 1:                   183454            1035373                 319540         2588950187             2396550000
> 2:                   241199            4272260                4826042        10682786130            36195315000
> 3:                   249506            1124098                1959866         2810807049            14698995000
> ```

which reproduces OP's expected result. Note that the variable names `vn` are created automagically.

---

Aggregation and grouping can be performed while reshaping

```
dcast(long, No_Adjusted_Gross_Income ~ range, sum, value.var = c("NoR", "AGI"))
```

> ```
>    No_Adjusted_Gross_Income NoR_from_1_to_5000 NoR_from_5000_to_10000 AGI_from_1_to_5000 AGI_from_5000_to_10000
> 1:                   183454            1035373                 319540         2588950187             2396550000
> 2:                   241199            4272260                4826042        10682786130            36195315000
> 3:                   249506            1124098                1959866         2810807049            14698995000
> ```

or

```
dcast(long, No_Adjusted_Gross_Income ~ ., sum, value.var = c("NoR", "AGI"))
```

> ```
>    No_Adjusted_Gross_Income     NoR         AGI
> 1:                   183454 1354913  4985500187
> 2:                   241199 9098302 46878101130
> 3:                   249506 3083964 17509802049
> ```

Alternatively, aggregation & grouping can be performed in long format:

```
long[, lapply(.SD, sum), .SDcols = c("NoR", "AGI"), by = No_Adjusted_Gross_Income]
```

> ```
>    No_Adjusted_Gross_Income     NoR         AGI
> 1:                   183454 1354913  4985500187
> 2:                   241199 9098302 46878101130
> 3:                   249506 3083964 17509802049
> ```

Comment: Thank you very much! Will try this first thing in the morning!